# Iframe Microsoft Graph and Sharepoint

Tags: c#, angular, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a question regarding Microsoft Graph and SharePoint.

Is it possible to generate a link using the API to view a SharePoint document in my application within an iframe without prompting for a Microsoft username and password?

The idea would be to achieve this using a token or something similar.

If not, how could I go about displaying a SharePoint document in my app?

The front-end is built in Angular, and the back-end is in C#. Where should it go?

I need to show in my app a document from SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by using Microsoft Graph API and SharePoint REST API to generate a link with an access token. You can then use this link within an iframe in your Angular application

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread